# Socket.io socket.emit/socket.on not working

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm writing an app where i have multiple socket.io custom events, and all work fine, except this one:

```
socket.on("incomingImg", function(data) {
          var newimagesrc = data.image
          alert("new image");
         $("#messages").append(

                $("<img id='image' src='" + newimagesrc +"' >").text(
                     data.sender + ": [IMAGE]: " +
                    data.image           
                )

              );
         //$("#image").attr("src", newimagesrc);
        });
```

I've confirmed all the JQuery works, the only issue here is that on every client except the one I send this from, nothing happens. It may be worth noting that the client that initially sends the message is sending a different event; my server code looks like this:

```
socket.on("sendImg", function(data) {
    var imgdata = data.imageurl;
    var sendername = data.uname;
    console.log(imgdata);
    console.log(sendername);
    socket.emit('incomingImg', { image: imgdata, sender: sendername 
    });
  });
```

for some reason, when `IncomingImg` is emitted, only the client that sent `sendImg` receives it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: socket.io has very subtle details that if not accounted for will give you unexpected results. Have you looked at the cheat sheet to confirm that you are doing the right thing?  https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/.  Seems to me that you need to broadcast or use io.emit but without more details on how you've configured things and what you specifically want I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, one of the subtle details that Pineapple Joe mentioned in his comment was the problem, although it was actually my error - there was a typo in the event name on the server. Correcting that fixed the problem.